# how to use slow_callback_duration to find blocking coroutines in asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm debugging some code where one coroutine is, I think, blocking another coroutine causing it to time out. I don't know where that is. I believe this toy code models my situation, or at least, a situation I want to understand:

```py
import asyncio
import logging
import sys
import time
import warnings

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format="%(asctime)s - %(levelname)7s: %(message)s",
    stream=sys.stderr,
)
logger = logging.getLogger("")
LOG = logger


async def timeout_checker():
    logger.info("starting timeout clock")
    t0 = time.time()
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    if time.time() - t0 > 3:
        raise asyncio.TimeoutError("timeout!")


async def selfish_sleeper():
    logger.info("selfish sleeping")
    time.sleep(4)
    logger.info(f"done sleeping")


async def two_level_sleeper():
    await selfish_sleeper()


async def timeshare():
    task = asyncio.create_task(timeout_checker())

    logger.info(f"created task, starting unselfish sleep")
    await asyncio.sleep(0.05)

    # await selfish_sleeper()
    await two_level_sleeper()

    result = await task
    logger.info(f"result {result}")


async def main():
    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    # Enable debugging
    event_loop.set_debug(True)

    # Make the threshold for "slow" tasks very very small for
    # illustration. The default is 0.1, or 100 milliseconds.
    event_loop.slow_callback_duration = 0.001

    # Report all mistakes managing asynchronous resources.
    warnings.simplefilter("always", ResourceWarning)

    await timeshare()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger.info("start")
    asyncio.run(main(), debug=True)
    logger.info("done")
```

In this toy, I was hoping to find something that could just tell me that `selfish_sleeper` is taking more time than expected. When I run this, I get:

```
2021-11-29 14:16:51,439 -    INFO: start
2021-11-29 14:16:51,440 -   DEBUG: Using selector: EpollSelector
2021-11-29 14:16:51,464 -    INFO: created task, starting unselfish sleep
2021-11-29 14:16:51,468 - WARNING: Executing <Task pending name='Task-1' coro=<main() running at /mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/mydir/selfish.py:60> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task.task_wakeup()] created at /home/me/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py:424> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at /home/me/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py:184] created at /home/me/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py:638> took 0.012 seconds
2021-11-29 14:16:51,468 -    INFO: starting timeout clock
2021-11-29 14:16:51,473 - WARNING: Executing <Task pending name='Task-2' coro=<timeout_checker() running at /mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/mydir/selfish.py:19> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task.task_wakeup()] created at /home/me/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py:424> created at /home/me/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py:337> took 0.004 seconds
2021-11-29 14:16:51,521 - WARNING: Executing <TimerHandle when=24730.752979659 _set_result_unless_cancelled(<Future finis...events.py:424>, None) at /home/me/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/asyncio/futures.py:308 created at /home/me/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py:605> took 0.003 seconds
2021-11-29 14:16:51,521 -    INFO: selfish sleeping
2021-11-29 14:16:55,526 -    INFO: done sleeping
2021-11-29 14:16:55,526 - WARNING: Executing <Task pending name='Task-1' coro=<main() running at /mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/mydir/selfish.py:60> wait_for=<Task pending name='Task-2' coro=<timeout_checker() running at /mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/mydir/selfish.py:19> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task.task_wakeup()] created at /home/me/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py:424> cb=[Task.task_wakeup()] created at /home/me/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py:337> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at /home/me/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py:184] created at /home/me/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py:638> took 4.005 seconds
2021-11-29 14:16:55,531 - WARNING: Executing <TimerHandle when=24730.806657506997 _set_result_unless_cancelled(<Future finis...events.py:424>, None) at /home/me/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/asyncio/futures.py:308 created at /home/me/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py:605> took 0.004 seconds
2021-11-29 14:16:55,535 - WARNING: Executing <Task finished name='Task-2' coro=<timeout_checker() done, defined at /mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/mydir/selfish.py:16> exception=TimeoutError('timeout!') created at /home/me/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py:337> took 0.004 seconds
2021-11-29 14:16:55,539 - WARNING: Executing <Task finished name='Task-1' coro=<main() done, defined at /mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/mydir/selfish.py:47> exception=TimeoutError('timeout!') created at /home/me/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py:638> took 0.003 seconds
2021-11-29 14:16:55,548 - WARNING: Executing <Task finished name='Task-3' coro=<BaseEventLoop.shutdown_asyncgens() done, defined at /home/me/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py:530> result=None created at /home/me/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py:638> took 0.003 seconds
2021-11-29 14:16:55,555 - WARNING: Executing <Task finished name='Task-4' coro=<BaseEventLoop.shutdown_default_executor() done, defined at /home/me/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py:555> result=None created at /home/me/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py:638> took 0.002 seconds
2021-11-29 14:16:55,560 -   DEBUG: Close <_UnixSelectorEventLoop running=False closed=False debug=True>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/mydir/selfish.py", line 65, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main(), debug=True)
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 641, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/mydir/selfish.py", line 60, in main
    await timeshare()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/mydir/selfish.py", line 43, in timeshare
    result = await task
  File "/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/mydir/selfish.py", line 21, in timeout_checker
    raise asyncio.TimeoutError("timeout!")
asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError: timeout!
```

where the message showing the excess time is:

```
2021-11-29 14:16:55,526 - WARNING: Executing <Task pending name='Task-1' coro=<main() running at /mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/mydir/selfish.py:60> wait_for=<Task pending name='Task-2' coro=<timeout_checker() running at /mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/mydir/selfish.py:19> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task.task_wakeup()] created at /home/me/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py:424> cb=[Task.task_wakeup()] created at /home/me/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py:337> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at /home/me/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py:184] created at /home/me/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py:638> took 4.005 seconds
```

Seems completely misleading: it seems to say that the time was spent in either `main` (which is too high level to be useful) or in `timeout_checker`, which isn't the case. I don't see any hint in that message for which coroutine *actually* consumed the time.

I'm sure a profiler (e.g., `yappi`) could find it, but I'm not sure I can use that in the context where the problem is arising. I was hopeful that `slow_callback_duration` would be sufficient. Am I using it incorrectly or misinterpreting what it's telling me?

Comment: `slow_callback_duration` apparently works at the callback/task granularity. From the perspective of the event loop, running a single step of `Task-1`, which drives execution of the `main()` coroutine, took 4.005 seconds. By the time the event loop regained control by the task suspending on an `await`, both `two_level_sleeper` and `selfish_sleeper` have completed and the event loop can't point a finger at them.

Comment: I don't think you can do much better than this, the feature is just cruder than you expected. It probably works well enough when there are many small tasks (hopefully with different names and entry points) and the task name/entry point is meaningful for debugging the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, your explanation seems reasonable to me. If you (or any future reader) care to find anything reasonably official looking and make it an answer, then I can mark it as accepted. fwiw, I tried `yappi`, and it was able to find the problem, so I'll focus on using that for finding scenarios like these.